# Domains and Communities in Salesforce

Tags: community, custom-domain, custom-url

Our customer has registered a domain name and pointed it to a force.com community (site) in Salesforce. So what happens is that www.somecooldomainname.be shows the home page of that force.com community.

What they are asking now is that a subdomain is created that points to a specific page of that same site. So they want that somecoolfeature.somecooldomainname.be points to a secondary page of the same force.com community.

Is this possible by using the "path" field of a custom URL. So first create the subdomain (somecoolfeature.somecooldomainname.be) as a domain in salesforce, point to the right site (the same as the main domain (www.somecooldomainname.be)) and the create a custom URL with as a value for "path" the name of the page.

Any feedback or tips would be very welcome.